# How to make a client-server communication without a Domain Name

Tags: dns, internet, ip, webserver, ipv4

In the context of a web application including clients and a web service (server), I want to have a client-server HTTP communication over internet.

I'm aware that the IP address is dynamic and may change, so it's not possible to identify the server with its IP address for the communication.

I know that I can use a domain name. I actually don't have one, but I found some online services like [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/) to achieve that. However, I would like to know if there's some other solutions for such a problem.

I've heard about tunneling or something like that but I don't have any clue about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make a client and server communication without a domain name?

You can use use the appropriate IP addresses to establish communication.

> The IP address of the server is dynamic and may change.

In this case, using a domain name is a better solution. Domain names are simply human-friendly aliases for IP addresses.

> I've heard about tunneling but I don't have any clue about it.

Tunneling is typically used to help data traverse a network that it might not otherwise be able to. However, to the best of my knowledge, this still typically requires a known destination.

---

> I know that I can use a domain name. However, I would like to know if there's another solution to this problem.

In theory, if you didn’t want a domain name attached directly to the server itself, you could have the server update the clients about its IP through some other means.

Hypothetically, you might:

1. Have the server contact the clients directly for this update.
2. Have the server contact an unrelated site and drop its IP as web-accessible text to that site.

In either case, a small program on the client would receive/retrieve this data.
How that data would be used on the client would be up to you. Some thoughts might be:

1. Drop it as text file.
2. Write the IP to the system's *hosts* file.
3. Create a script to launch a specific program/process with the appropriate IP.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and the clear explanations :). the second solution seems clear (y) ... what about the first one ? how can the server contact the clients directly ? they are not in the same network (communicating through internet), no one has the ip address of the other as long as they are dynamic.

Comment: The first solution would rely on the server knowing who all the clients are (via a list that the server would check). If the client IPs were dynamic, the list could be consistently updated by the clients (i.e. via another intermediary, similar to Solution 2). That said, I would say that having clients check for the server IP address (rather than vice versa) would be the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for answer... i found another service [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and it uses tunnel " technology " ... but i don't get it clearly according to your definition ... can you please explain me why they use " tunnels to localhost " ? how can tunneling (or encapsulating a protocol inside another one) is supposed to make it possible to contact a localhost from outside ?

Comment: Apologies. When traversing NAT, for instance, the computers behind NAT can typically only receive packets that they request. So a persistent connection (a "tunnel") is established from the computer behind NAT to a known remote host (e.g. ngrok) and any data sent across the tunnel is encapsulated to facilitate its transportation. That is, the data portion of the tunnel packets are used to carry the packets that actually provide the required service (e.g. HTTP).

Comment: Regarding firewalls, they often block particular protocols, but will pass data that is encapsulated inside a protocol that the firewall doesn't block (so tunneling can help in this case).

Comment: Concerning services such as ngrok, web servers expect incoming requests (client to server) to establish a connection (which may not be possible with NAT/firewalls in place). So someone on the outside who wants to contact a web server behind NAT/firewall would contact e.g. ngrok, who would then use the tunnel from its servers to the web server (which would have already been previously established by the web server) to relay data back and forth.

Comment: Clear answer (y), sorry for being too late

Comment: Not a problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your ISP changes your IP address you may ask him
for a fixed IP address (some ISPs will ask some payment for allocating
that number). Note that usually, as long as the router is not turned off
it will keep its external IP address.

Or you may use a dynamic DNS service that gives you a DNS address
on their server that is automatically updated when your computer
or router is booted. My router's firmware has this capability.
An example is [Dyn DNS](https://dyn.com/).

Comment: I'm using a fixed port number, my problem is not the port number, it's in the fact that the IP address is dynamic.

Comment: My misunderstanding. I have rewritten my answer for using dynamic IP.

Comment: Unfortunatly my ISP doesn't provide fixed IP address, and i'm more like looking for free solution as it's for a pedagogic project ... and thanks for the DNS solution ... i noticed that my router also uses a DDNS service :D